# Is it possible to have an ngOptions dropdown expand on focus?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I click on a  then the ngOptions list is expanded. Is it possible to get the same behaviour onFocus during keyboard navigation?

Comment: I'm not sure what more information you want. I have a select with a bunch of ngoptions. If I click the select element, the options expand so I can click one. If instead I navigate to the select element by tabbing, the ngpotions list is NOT expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive, that attaches a focus event to a select tag and manipulate the [**size property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) of the select tag during focus and blur. Below is a code snippet that includes a directive, `expandFocus`, that demonstrates expansion of the select options on focus and its contraction on blur.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.colors = [
        {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
        {name:'white', shade:'light'},
        {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
        {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
        {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
     ];
  })

  .directive('expandFocus', function() {
     return function(scope, jqElem, attr) {
         var elem = jqElem[0],
             tag = elem.tagName.toLowerCase();

         if(tag == 'select') {
          jqElem.on('focus', function() {
               elem.size = elem.length;
            });

            jqElem.on('blur', function() {
               elem.size = 0; // normally you would use 1 but firefox uses 0.
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              elem.off('focus');
              elem.off('blur');
            });
         }
     };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <select ng-options="color.name for color in colors" ng-model="mainColor" name="mainColor" expand-focus>
      <option value=""> -- Select </option>
   </select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. So it was the length that I needed to poke. Very many thanks.

Comment: It's the size actually, but you need the select's length to change the size.